# Efficiency of a supercomputer. Alternatives to rent one to process large amount of data

Tags: efficiency

I want to live from poker as I don't find a job as geologist, and I am making a trainning system to train myself. I need to process some data to calculate the mathematical chances for each 270.000 posible hands -the variety is omaha, permutations of 52 cards in groups of 4- against all the other posible hands of the poker deck, and my computer would take several months to process them -I am gonna say for posible calcles 20 months-.

I have an i5 with 16 GB RAM:

```
Arquitectura:                        x86_64
modo(s) de operación de las CPUs:    32-bit, 64-bit
Orden de bytes:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                              4
On-line CPU(s) list:                 0-3
Hilo(s) de procesamiento por núcleo: 1
Núcleo(s) por «socket»:              4
Socket(s):                           1
Modo(s) NUMA:                        1
ID de fabricante:                    GenuineIntel
Familia de CPU:                      6
Modelo:                              158
Model name:                          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz
Revisión:                            9
CPU MHz:                             900.049
CPU max MHz:                         3500,0000
CPU min MHz:                         800,0000
BogoMIPS:                            6000.00
Virtualización:                      VT-x
Caché L1d:                           32K
Caché L1i:                           32K
Caché L2:                            256K
Caché L3:                            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):                   0-3
```

I am interested in renting a supercomputer for an hour and I have the money to rent it, but it is an expensive cost for me.

> My question is double before deciding what to do:
>
> **i) Would the supercomputer solve the calculations in a short time, being enough an hour of rental?**
>
> **ii) Are there better alternatives such as deriving the calculations to a server of a certain capacity paying a month?**

If option ii) takes one or two weeks paying eg 100 $, I can wait a week or two, I will skip current step and continue doing calcles that my pc can do. But I wonder if the sc would solve it in a few minuts, so then, my project will continue, and I may prepare my hole trainning system scripts in some months and pay for their execution and generated data later.

I need help from someone that knows how fast are that computers to planify the continuation of my project, or provide a better/cheaper alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should tell about your script. Most likely it is not parallelized and you only use one core. In this case supercomputer will most likely not solve your problems, because I suspect they have the same one core performance as your home computer.

Comment: I planned to do multithread. But then a supercomputer rented wouldn't solved it in real-life time? It is calculating the chances for 4 poker cards -from 52- 270.000 hands against all the other hands. -2 players, 3, 4,5 and 6-

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: python is the language I use

Comment: I said 20 months, but I just suspect it....I am currently writing the script. But if I am gonna live from that I will need to do more calcs in the future...

Comment: Moving to any compiled language will accelerate the speed about 100 times depending on what you do (fastest is C/C++). Using Cython and numba can also accelerate the calculations in python.

Comment: Definitively it is time to me to start to learn some C++. But for minning the data of my .txt hands files I will continue using python -I have started a big data master and we use python-. But then @keiv.fly for that 20 months calculations. Can't I just rent one an hour or take a big droplet for some weeks? wouldn't it solve the '20 months' calculations?

Comment: My trainning program don't needs efficiency @keiv.fly. Shows 4 random cards and you decide if they are good enougth to put chips. In a second next tactic problem will be shown on my pc with no troubles. I am making the GUI in tkinter and everything I do is on python. Once I have the 270000 rows database with the data I need, I can show data in real-time. But I have actualy 20.000 hands stored, and I have just started (!), so I think I will do more hard calcles of my oponnents mouvements if it is gonna be my job, and definitively I am moving to C++, so thanks for the advice ;) (100 times!).

Comment: The smart way is to benchmark, find slow places and change the code of slow places to work in Cython. Then use Cython functions in Python. Cython is Python with some peculiarities. A good profiling tool for Python is line_profiler.

Comment: And Python does not support multithreading because of the GIL. You can only do multi multiprocessing. Rewriting code to work in parallel is an art in itself. Some algorithms are not parallizable.

Comment: Too much complex for a geologist ....@keiv.fly So then I should write the deep scripts on multithread C++ (Java is ok to me also, I started to learn with it). I will also take a look on Cython, I don't know if I will hear about it on the following lessons of my bd master. ty

Comment: If by deep you mean neutral networks then you should also try using Nvidea GPU for Keras and Tensorflow. It is 20 times faster on GPU than on CPU.

Comment: @keiv.fly by they will probably talk me about that on my studies,but I have just started them. I have the database with the 270.000 posible hands (permutations of 52 elements in groups of 4). I need to fill it comparing wiht the other 140.000 posible hands -permutations of 48 grouped 4-. I have the method written on python comparing two hands. But as each hand has 60 posible hands it is to launch the method 270.000x140.000x60=2.268e+12 times....to continue....

Comment: You can do random sampling. Even small random samples are usually a good approximation of the whole distribution

Comment: @keiv.fly Thanks for that advice! I am gonna calculate one or two hands and see when % of random sampling get close to absolute value. That may allow me to continue soon with other not so long calcles of the game. I will confirm you it worked!